# 3D Spline Interpolation Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have two 3D arrays:

```
 A=[
12751   4616    15915
15864   4622    15667
12877   4683    21050
15816   4668    21253
11374   5006    18495
16995   5466    18493
11638   4880    20023
17078   4938    20006
11576   4886    17011
];
```

and

```
 B=[
12402   2138    15743
10285   3175    15851
10237   3084    21052
12130   2129    21299
8074    3802    18505
14515   1623    18497
8415    3713    19856
14462   1120    20061
8340    3711    17145
14483   1157    16990];
```

and I want to do spline or 3D interpolation between them using `Interp3` in Matlab.How should I define `V` in `VI = interp3(X,Y,Z,V,XI,YI,ZI)`?

Or `Y` in `yy = spline(x,Y,xx)`.

Comment: Those arrays look very **two** dimensional to me...

Comment: What do these arrays represent? Note: in absolutely NO case will interp3 be the correct tool for interpolation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand your data, is `B` a function of `A` (or visa versa)? Also, those arrays appear to be 1D, not 3D. Can you clarify this?

In your function call

```
yy = spline(x, Y, xx)
```

`Y` is the dependent variable which you are interpolating: `Y` is a function of `x` and the result of the above function call is to return the value of `Y` at `xx`. As an example in one dimension, try

```
x = linspace(0., 2.*pi, 100);
Y = sin(x);

% What is the value of Y (or sin(x)) at pi/2?
xx = pi/2.;
yy = spline(x, Y, xx); % This should result in yy = 1.000
```

Check out the [`spline` documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/spline.html) for more information and examples of using this function.

Now this function is only for 1D fitting, and is (I presume) equivalent to `yy = interp1(x, Y, xx, 'spline')`. If you want to do a three dimensional lookup, you'll have to use `interp3`, which generalises the above example to 3D. So rather than just one independent coordinate `x`, we have two more, `y`, and `z` and three coordinates for the point at which we want to perform the look up: `xx`, `yy` and `zz`. The function you are interpolating must be a 3D function of the coordinates `(x, y, z)`. Try, as an example:

```
x = linspace(-1., 1., 100); y = x; z = x;
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(x, y, z);
s = exp(-sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2 + Z.^2));

sinterp = interp3(x, y, z, s, 0., 0., 0.) % Should give sinterp = 0.9827
```